# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' and how to avoid it?

Tags: python, inheritance

I get the following error when running scrapeBackend.py

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I am trying to use the send_topic method inherited from the ProducerConsumer class in customKafka.py

```
import time
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from customKafka import ProducerConsumer


class scrapeBackend(ProducerConsumer):

    def run(self):
        ARTICLE_SCRAPED_KAFKA_TOPIC = "raw_text"
        ARTICLE_LIMIT = 20
        print("Generating raw article")
        print("generating every 3 seconds")

        for i in range(1,ARTICLE_LIMIT):
            data={
                "article_id": i,
                "source" : "bbc",
                "article" : "this is an article"
            }
            super().send_topic("raw_text",data)
            #collection.insert_one(data)
            print(f"done sending {i}")
            time.sleep(3)

scrap1=scrapeBackend(True,False,"raw_text","localhost:29092")

scrap1.run()
```

customKafka.py

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
class ProducerConsumer:
    __isProducer=None
    __isConsumer=None
    __producer=None
    __consumer=None

    def __init__(self,isProducer,isConsumer,topic,bootstrap_servers):
        if (self.__isProducer):
            self.__producer=KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)
        if (self.__isConsumer):
            self.__consumer= KafkaConsumer(
                topic,
                bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
                auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                enable_auto_commit=True,
                consumer_timeout_ms = 10000)

    def get_producer(self):
        return self.__producer

    def get_consumer(self):
        return self.__consumer

    def send_topic(self,topic,data):
        self.get_producer().send(topic, json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))
```

Looks like the getProducer() is returning None however it should return something since I initaliazed before running

Comment: Inside `ProducerConsumer.__init___` you mean `if self.__isProducer`  or `if isProducer`  OR `if self.__isProducer is None` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `__init__` function of parent class.

It should be implemented like this:

```
def __init__(self,isProducer,isConsumer,topic,bootstrap_servers):
        if isProducer:
            self.__producer=KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)
        if isConsumer:
            self.__consumer= KafkaConsumer(
                topic,
                bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
                auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                enable_auto_commit=True,
                consumer_timeout_ms = 10000)
```

Notice the difference in the if statements. Hope this helps!!

Comment: `if isProducer` and `if isConsumer`

Comment: Thank you it works! but why is self.isProducer inappropriate in this case?

Comment: self.isProducer will look for the variable(property) of the class itself, while isProducer will refer to the function parameter

Answer (score 0):

you should call `super()` in your `__init__` of the subclass then, you should be able to call the function `send_topic` from the object `scrap1`

```py
class scrapeBackend(ProducerConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(scrapeBackend, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        ARTICLE_SCRAPED_KAFKA_TOPIC = "raw_text"
        ARTICLE_LIMIT = 20
        print("Generating raw article")
        print("generating every 3 seconds")

        for i in range(1,ARTICLE_LIMIT):
            data={
                "article_id": i,
                "source" : "bbc",
                "article" : "this is an article"
            }
            self.send_topic("raw_text", data)
            #collection.insert_one(data)
            print(f"done sending {i}")
            time.sleep(3)
```

and your `__init__` of `ProductConsumer` can't deal with input parameters (the 2 if-conditions), it should be implemented like this:

```py
class ProducerConsumer:
    def __init__(self,isProducer,isConsumer,topic,bootstrap_servers):
        if isProducer:
            self.__producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)
        if isConsumer:
            self.__consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                topic,
                bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
                auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                enable_auto_commit=True,
                consumer_timeout_ms = 10000)

    def get_producer(self):
        return self.__producer

    def get_consumer(self):
        return self.__consumer

    def send_topic(self,topic,data):
        self.get_producer().send(topic, json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))
```